# Is it possible to have two files of translation for the same language?

Tags: symfony, translation

Can I have two translation files for the same language ? for example :

messages1.fr.yml

```
  hello: "Salut"
```

messages2.fr.yml

```
  here: "ici"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called [translation domain](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation.html#using-message-domains)

```
{{ "hello"|trans({},"messages1") }}
{{ "here"|trans({},"messages2") }}
```

To use it in controller it is the same logic:
the args are `the key`, `the array of parameters` then `the translation domain`

```
$this->get('translator')->trans('key', [], 'yourDomain);
```

In your case

```
$this->get('translator')->trans('hello', [], 'message1);
```

The [translation documentation is here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html)

Comment: It works very well thanks And how I can do this in controller ?